# Build automation, VMWare server 2.0, Final builder

Tags: vbscript, build-process, vmware, finalbuilder, vmware-tools

I have a database in a VMWare Server 2.0 Virtual machine. I also have a web application in the IIS (7) in the VM.

Now I want to execute some database scripts that are in the VM, from the Host machine.
Also I have a VB script in the VM that I want to run from the Host machine.

How do I go about setting this up. I can buy Final builder if that will help me.

Since I am looking to automate the above from the Host machine, I was wondering what I would have to do to execute the database and the VB scripts that are in the VM, but execute them from the Host machine, so that these update the database and IIS (vb script thing) in the VM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to configure the VM with a network connection that is reachable from the host machine, and run the scripts across the network connection the same as you would if you had a physical machine instead of a virtual machine.  If your goal is to keep the VM isolated from your existing network and servers, then you need merely configure a private network between the host and the guest, and use that.  With this approach, you don't need any extra software.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to attach a host share as a network drive and then use vmrun. Here is an example:

```
    vmrun -T server -h https://hostname:8333/sdk -u root -p mypassword -gu administrator -gp guestpaswd 
  runProgramInGuest "[Vol1] win2008-1/win2008-1.vmx" -activeWindow "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

Surely, the VmWare Tools are to be installed.